# Find the number of employees in each office - Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to display how many staffs work in each office along with the offices name, but I can't get it to work. I have tried this

```
select count(*) as count,office_staff.staff_id
from staff
inner join office_staff on staff.staff_id = office_staff.staff_id
group by staff.staff_id
```

but the output I am getting is this :

```
# count, staff_id
'1', '1001'
'1', '1002'
'1', '1003'
'1', '1004'
'1', '1005'
'1', '1006'
```

Tables

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`staff` (
  `staff_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `office_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`office_staff`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`office_staff` (
  `office_staff_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `staff_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `office_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`offices`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`offices` (
  `office_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `address_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

Can anyone help me with it? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a column in your `offices` table called `Name` (your structure cuts off).  The reason I'm pulling the `Name` is because of this line:

> I am trying to display how many staffs work in each office along with the offices name

This should be all you need to do (change the column name as needed):

```
Select  O.Name   As OfficeName,
        Count(*) As count
From    staff        S
Join    office_staff OS On S.staff_id = OS.staff_id
Join    office       O  On O.Office_Id = OS.Office_Id
Group By O.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use office id instead of staff_id

```
  select count(*) as count, office_staff.office_id
  from staff
  inner join office_staff on staff.staff_id = office_staff.staff_id
  group by office_staff.office_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select count(*) as count,office_id
from staff, office_staff
inner join office_staff on staff.staff_id = office_staff.staff_id
group by office.id
```